# GPUImage background music stop

Tags: ios, gpuimage

use `GPUImageMovieWriter` recording video(other music app is background playing), but set `audioEncodingTarget` is `movieWriter`, music is stoped.
how continue playing

Comment: set AVAudioSession category is AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord not working.

Answer (score 0):

I resoveled this problem, we must set a property for automaticallyConfiguresApplicationAudioSession as NO before startCameraCapture.like this:

self.gpuCamera.captureSession.automaticallyConfiguresApplicationAudioSession.automaticallyConfiguresApplicationAudioSession = NO;

[self.gpuCamera startCameraCapture];

Answer (score 0):

i set `automaticallyConfiguresApplicationAudioSession = NO;`
and
'[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers error:nil];'

the background music still stoped.
for we used'[camera addAudioInputsAndOutputs]'

this must be set at first,or when configuation the preview will flash(auto focus)
    '- (BOOL)addAudioInputsAndOutputs
    {
    if (audioOutput)
        return NO;

```
[_captureSession beginConfiguration];

_microphone = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio];
audioInput = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:_microphone error:nil];
if ([_captureSession canAddInput:audioInput])
{
    [_captureSession addInput:audioInput];
}
audioOutput = [[AVCaptureAudioDataOutput alloc] init];

if ([_captureSession canAddOutput:audioOutput])
{
    [_captureSession addOutput:audioOutput];
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Couldn't add audio output");
}
[audioOutput setSampleBufferDelegate:self queue:audioProcessingQueue];

[_captureSession commitConfiguration];
return YES;
}'
```

it seems caused by the audio input and output.